# Cannot connect aura with apex class

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I'm following this tutorial for Address autocomplete. I have my Lightning component like this:
addressSearch.cmp:

```
<aura:component controller="AddressSearchController" implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
        <aura:attribute name="addressDetails" type="AddressDetails__c"/>
```

and my AddressSearchController.cls

```
public with sharing class AddressSearchController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static AddressDetails__c getAddressDetailsbyId(String id) {
        AddressDetails__c ad = new AddressDetails__c();
        ad = [select Id, City__c, State__c, Country__c, PostalCode__c, Street__C from AddressDetails__c where Id = :id];
        return ad;
    }
```

I got an error "Cannot resolve symbol AddressDetails__c, although I include @AuraEnabled and controller

Comment: Dont use the same variable name as the type.

Comment: The idea is ad has type AddressDetails__c

Comment: Does the AddressDetails__c custom object actually exist on the org to which you are deploying this code? If it does, the code [should work](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_returning_data.htm)... note that it is fragile, because you assume you get an instance back from the select (and if the ID no longer exists you will get an error). Also, no need for the "new AddressDetails__c()" call - this in-memory object is immediately discarded due to the following assignment.

Comment: Show full component body, as well as js controller